# Discord bot not getting all users

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have written a discord bot using Discord.js and it used to get all the users of the discord server (I have the bot in one discord server only), but now it only gets 59 members. I have 300+ discord users in the server.

```
var Discord = require('discord.js');
var bot = new Discord.Client();

function getUsers() {
  let users = bot.users.array();

  for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    let username = `${users[i].username}#${users[i].discriminator}`;
    console.log(`[${i}] ${username}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ar there any differences between the 59 members returned and the other one's?

Comment: no only that there is not the total anymore i think after it hit 250+ members in the server it stopped getting the total and only did 59 - 64

Comment: I'm using version 12 and I have similar issues. The cache is not holding all the users in the server. I don't know how to load the users to cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the method [`.fetchMembers()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchMembers) for every discord server the bot is in.

Try to use the following code:

```
function getUsers() {
  let guilds = bot.guilds.array();

  for (let i = 0; i < guilds.length; i++) {
    bot.guilds.get(guilds[i].id).fetchMembers().then(r => {
      r.members.array().forEach(r => {
        let username = `${r.user.username}#${r.user.discriminator}`;
        console.log(`${username}`);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I got an error.
(node:4657) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: bot.guilds.get(...).fetchMembers(...).array is not a function
    at getUsers (/home/sexyexploits/Documents/discord bot/Versions/0.0.11/le.js:98:69)
    at Client.bot.on (/home/sexyexploits/Documents/discord bot/Versions/0.0.11/le.js:21:3)

Comment: I updated my answer, can you try the new code please? :-)

Comment: Note that as of August 2021, `.fetchMembers()` was deprecated and has been replaced by `guild.members.fetch()`

Comment: You are welcome to edit my post to correct this issue @Guy

Comment: Tips: Just do `r.user.tag` and it will show a whole username and tag, with hashtag

Answer (score 5):

There's a discord-side setting that may be relevant here.

> If your bot tracks server members or downloads the entire member list, you may need the server members intent to receive member events and the member list.

Go to https://discord.com/developers/ and select your Discord application, go to the Bot settings, and enable "Server members intent" under "Priviliged gateway intents".

[image: Priviliged Gateway Intents > Server Members Intent]

Source: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/3774#issuecomment-717824144

Answer (score 2):

Bit late to the party here, but `<Client>.users` only returns the **cached** users at that point. Discord.js caches a member when they, for example, send a message or when you fetch that particular member. You would have to go through each member of the guild using `<Guild>.fetchMembers()` which returns the `member` objects of each and every one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using discord.js v12 it should be `guild.members.fetch()` which will cache all the members.

Comment: I have been having the same problem. But unfortuntely this doesn't work for me. I get an error message saying `Members didn't arrive in time.` and the bot crashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var usersCount = client.guilds.cache.reduce((a, g) => a + g.memberCount, 0)
```

This worked for me...